# Using useState for a slider - not working

Tags: react-hooks, slider

[Slider component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu58o.png)

[SliderItem component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8eu3.png)

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iij9P.png)

Can someone help me with this issue?

Im expecting to increase the "currentTab" with + 1 when the button "Next slide" is pressed

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75345886/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: provide the example code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using filter which should be used to filter the items array before map which is responsible for rendering, better check if slide index is current  and then render it

for example :

```
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Slider/>
    </div>
  );
}


const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Slide 1',
    description: 'Description 1',
    image: 'https://picsum.photos/800/400?image=0',
  },
  {
    id: 2,

    title: 'Slide 2',
    description: 'Description 2',
    image: 'https://picsum.photos/800/400?image=1',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Slide 3',
    description: 'Description 3',
    image: 'https://picsum.photos/800/400?image=2',
  }];

const Slider = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
  const length = items.length

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1)
  }

  return (
    <section className="slider">
      {items
      .map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={index === current ? 'slide active' : 'slide'}
            key={item.id}
          >
            {index === current && (
              <>
              <img src={item.image} alt="travel image" className="image" />
             <button onClick={nextSlide}>next</button>
            </>
            )}
          </div>
        )
      })}
      
    </section>
  )
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-wilson-xpdiyg?file=/src/App.js